# Validity of Statistics in Data Mining

Tags: data-mining

While I was going through Oracle Data Mining, found a interesting statement.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DMCON/process.htm#DMCON115

> ***Data Mining and Statistics***
>
> There is a great deal of overlap between
> data mining and statistics. In fact most of the techniques used in
> data mining can be placed in a statistical framework. However, data
> mining techniques are not the same as traditional statistical
> techniques.
>
> Statistical models usually make strong assumptions about the data and,
> based on those assumptions, they make strong statements about the
> results. However, if the assumptions are flawed, the validity of the
> model becomes questionable. By contrast, the machine learning methods
> used in data mining typically make weak assumptions about the data. As
> a result, data mining cannot generally make such strong statements
> about the results. Yet data mining can produce very good results
> regardless of the data.
>
> Traditional statistical methods, in general, require a great deal of
> user interaction in order to validate the correctness of a model. As a
> result, statistical methods can be difficult to automate. Statistical
> methods rely on testing hypotheses or finding correlations based on
> smaller, representative samples of a larger population.
>
> Less user interaction and less knowledge of the data is required for
> data mining. The user does not need to massage the data to guarantee
> that a method is valid for a given data set. Data mining techniques
> are easier to automate than traditional statistical techniques.

What does it mean by "Strong and Weak statement?"